# CKEditor doesn't show in production mode in Angular 17 and causes an error

Tags: angular, ckeditor, esbuild

I use `ckeditor5-angular` and `ckeditor5-build-classic` with Angular 17. In development mode it works truly, but in production mode, it doesn't work and causes:

> ERROR TypeError: this is not a constructor

My component:

```
  public Editor = ClassicEditor;
    public config = {
        language: 'fa',
        link: {
            addTargetToExternalLinks: true
        }
    };
```

My view:

```html
<div class="col-12 mb-3">
                <label class="col-form-label flex-grow-1">body</label>
                <ckeditor formControlName="body" [config]="config" [editor]="Editor" row="10"></ckeditor>
</div>
```

My [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/) [CKEditor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor) version:

```javascript
   "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^6.0.1",
   "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^34.2.0",
```

My Angular version:

```javascript
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "17.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "17.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "17.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "17.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "17.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.2",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^18.4.3",
    "@commitlint/config-angular": "^18.4.3",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^18.4.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "6.13.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "6.13.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.54.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^3.0.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.0",
    "prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^16.2.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
```

My *angular.json* builder configuration:

```javascript
 "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/Admin",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
```

*angular.json* production configuration:

```javascript
   "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "30mb",
              "maximumError": "30mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "20kb",
              "maximumError": "20kb"
            }
          ]
        },
```

I tried to change the ckeditor5 version to the latest, but it didn't work.

Comment: please share the error stacktrace, if possible the replicable code needs to be shared, best if its a stackblitz also!